# Go Anaconda twitter media upload with tweet

Tags: twitter, go

I can tweet, and upload media, but I cannot figure out how to tweet with the media using anaconda("github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda"). The media_id in the example was from a sucessfull media upload call.

```
mediaResponse, err := api.UploadMedia("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")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

//v := url.Values{}
//v.Set("media_ids", string(mediaResponse.MediaID))
fmt.Println(mediaResponse)
tweet := `
"media_ids": 612877656984416256,
"status": "hello"
`

result, err := api.PostTweet(tweet, nil)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Can someone assist in telling me how to parse the json or call the PostTweet with the media id? I've also tried adding the media to url.Values without sucess.

Comment: This doesn't look like legal json: tweet := `
"media_ids": 612877656984416256,
"status": "hello"
`

Comment: tweet := `{
"media_ids": 612877656984416256,
"status": "hello"
}`

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/efW0Hw1lic for an example of generating and parsing json in go.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everyone. I see that the json was invalid but the issue was an error passing the media_ids parameter. The response was: "errors":[{"code":44,"message":"media_ids parameter is invalid."}] which i though erroring out on the formatting but it had to do with not converting the media_ids type int64 to a string correctly. Here is the fixed code:

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

mediaResponse, err := api.UploadMedia(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(data))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

v := url.Values{}
v.Set("media_ids", strconv.FormatInt(mediaResponse.MediaID, 10))

result, err := api.PostTweet(posttitle, v)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid json:

```
tweet := `
"media_ids": 612877656984416256,
"status": "hello"
`
```

Try using this to generate your json:

```
type Tweet struct {
    MediaIds uint64 `json:"media_ids"`
    Status   string `json:"status"`
}
tweet := Tweet{612877656984416256, "hello"}
b, err := json.Marshal(tweet)
```

This results in :

```
{"media_ids":612877656984416256,"status":"hello"}
```

This has a few benefits over using a raw string.

1. It is more go centric. The struct can be passed around with values set and read with proper type checking caught at compile time.
2. The generated json string is more likely to be semantically correct. e.g. Go will also escape certain characters to help ensure they will be parsed properly by the receiver.